# AssertionError on trying to add new entity using matcher on spaCy

Tags: named-entity-recognition, spacy

I'm trying to match all e-mail like looking text in a bunch of documents and add it to custom NER label called 'EMAIL'. 
Here is the code for a test case.

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

EMAIL = nlp.vocab.strings['EMAIL']

def add_email_ent(matcher, doc, i, matches):
    match_id, start, end = matches[i]
    doc.ents += ((EMAIL, start, end),)

matcher.add('EmailPII', add_email_ent, [{'LIKE_EMAIL': True}])

text = u"Hi, this is John. My email is john@ymail.com and an alternate is john@gmail.com"
doc = nlp(text)

matches = matcher(doc)
for i,[match_id, start, end] in enumerate(matches):
    print (i+1, doc[start:end])

for ent in doc.ents:
    print (ent.text, ent.label_)
```

Here's what I get when I run this code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/emailpii.py", line 26, in <module>
    matches = matcher(doc)
  File "matcher.pyx", line 407, in spacy.matcher.Matcher.__call__
  File "C:/Python27/emailpii.py", line 19, in add_event_ent
    doc.ents += ((EMAIL, start, end),)
  File "doc.pyx", line 415, in spacy.tokens.doc.Doc.ents.__get__
  File "span.pyx", line 61, in spacy.tokens.span.Span.__cinit__
AssertionError: 17587345535198158200
```

However, on running a similar example

```
import spacy


print "*****************"
print(spacy.__version__)
print "*****************"


from spacy.matcher import Matcher
#from spacy import displacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

EVENT = nlp.vocab.strings['EVENT']

def add_event_ent(matcher, doc, i, matches):
    match_id, start, end = matches[i]
    doc.ents += ((EVENT, start, end),)

matcher.add('GoogleIO', add_event_ent,
            [{'ORTH': 'Google'}, {'ORTH': 'I'}, {'ORTH': '/'}, {'ORTH': 'O'}],
            [{'ORTH': 'Google'}, {'ORTH': 'I'}, {'ORTH': '/'}, {'ORTH': 'O'}, {'IS_DIGIT': True}])

text = u"Google I/O was great this year. See you all again in Google I/O 2018"
doc = nlp(text)

matches = matcher(doc)
for i,[match_id, start, end] in enumerate(matches):
    print (i, doc[start:end])

for ent in doc.ents:
    print (ent.text, ent.label_)

#displacy.serve(doc, style = 'ent')
```

I get the output as desired:

---

2.0.1

---

(0, Google I/O)

(1, Google I/O)

(2, Google I/O 2018)

(u'Google I/O', u'EVENT')

(u'this year', u'DATE')

(u'Google I/O 2018', u'EVENT')

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your first code fails because you have not added an Entity label for 'EMAIL'. The second code works because EVENT is a pre-existing Entity type.

The documentation is not very clear on what the first argument of the `matcher.add()` method actually does, but it adds an Entity label for you. Here are two alternatives that should work and clear up the confusion:

Alternative 1:

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

#EMAIL = nlp.vocab.strings['EMAIL'] #Not needed

def add_email_ent(matcher, doc, i, matches):
    match_id, start, end = matches[i]
    doc.ents += ((match_id, start, end),)

matcher.add('EMAIL', add_email_ent, [{'LIKE_EMAIL': True}])

text = u"Hi, this is John. My email is john@ymail.com and an alternate is john@gmail.com"
doc = nlp(text)

matches = matcher(doc)
for i,[match_id, start, end] in enumerate(matches):
    print (i+1, doc[start:end])

for ent in doc.ents:
    print (ent.text, ent.label_)
```

Alternative 2 (I'm not sure why you'd want to do it this way because you end up with two entity labels serving essentially the same purpose, but provided just for illustration purposes):

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
from spacy.pipeline import EntityRecognizer

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
ner = EntityRecognizer(nlp.vocab)

ner.add_label('EMAIL')

EMAIL = nlp.vocab.strings['EMAIL']

def add_email_ent(matcher, doc, i, matches):
    match_id, start, end = matches[i]
    doc.ents += ((EMAIL, start, end),)

matcher.add('EmailPII', add_email_ent, [{'LIKE_EMAIL': True}])

text = u"Hi, this is John. My email is john@ymail.com and an alternate is john@gmail.com"
doc = nlp(text)

matches = matcher(doc)
for i,[match_id, start, end] in enumerate(matches):
    print (i+1, doc[start:end])

for ent in doc.ents:
    print (ent.text, ent.label_)
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me understand the first argument passed into matcher.add function. I'd addressed my issue by using 'add_label' and also 'assert'ing the span. Waited to get a better way of implementing it though. This helps.